# Use a variable in a Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, case

I am trying to get a result from a table dependent on a field and populate the variable from different fields dependent on one of the fields.  Here is what I have

```
DECLARE  @MyText Text; 
SELECT 
bu4contart,
CASE WHEN bu4contart IN('40HR', '40RF') THEN
     'Temp: ' + bu4setpoint
ELSE 
     'Oversize: ' + bu4ohtop
END AS @MyText
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: And the problem is...? What DBMS? What version? What do your tables and data look like? This is _so_ vague.

Comment: You can't set variables and select data in the same query.  Plus a variable can only hold _one_ value. What is the purpose of the variable?  Are you expecting the query to concatenate all values into the single text variable?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax provided

Comment: So what we are trying to do is display a text field in a Crystal Report.  But the value of that field will depend on what type of container it is. (bu4contart).  If it is a 40HR or 40RF then we want to display a temperature (bu4setpoint) else display Oversize dimensions (bu4ohtop).  Any ideas of how to do this?  SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you want a scalar value from a (possibly) set of rows.  This could work for a scalar situation.

```
DECLARE  @MyText Text = 
(SELECT Top 1

CASE WHEN bu4contart IN('40HR', '40RF') THEN
     'Temp: ' + bu4setpoint
ELSE 
     'Oversize: ' + bu4ohtop
END AS MyText
FROM MyTable
Order By FieldThatOrdersForTop1FromMultipleRowsIfNecessary
)
```

Comment: Thank You Joe C works great!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
DECLARE  @MyText varchar(max);
DECLARE  @sql varchar(max);

SET @MyText = 'ahahahha';

SET @sql='SELECT 
    bu4contart,
    CASE WHEN bu4contart IN(''40HR'', ''40RF'') THEN
        ''Temp: '' + bu4setpoint
    ELSE 
         ''Oversize: '' + bu4ohtop
    END AS ' + @MyText  
    + ' FROM MyTable';

EXECUTE (@sql)
```